# how to configure routes in Laravel so that they access the alias and not the main domain

Tags: laravel, routes, alias, middleware

Good afternoon. Please tell me, maybe someone has encountered this.

I have a website with the domain site-testing.com.

I have set up an alias for this site -
site-testing.info.

There is a route -

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'posts', 'as' => 'posts.site-testing.'], function () {
    Route::get('/{slug}', [PostController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
});
```

When I write a named route in a blade file

```
<a href="{{route('posts.site-testing.show', $post->slug)}}">Read more</a>
```

then all links lead to the main domain, that is, to

http://site-testing.com/posts/slug

and not to an alias domain,

http://site-testing.info/posts/slug

Can you please tell me how to make the route point to an alias?
(https://site-testing.info/posts/slug)

and not to the main domain (https://site-testing.com/posts/slug)

I can’t find a solution yet, the routes are always worked out in such a way that they lead to the main domain of the project, and not to an alias

Comment: `posts.site-testing.show` is just the name/alias of the route, it has nothing to do with the domain used.

Comment: yes, but it opens
 http://site-testing.com/posts/slug

but not alias
https://site-testing.info/posts/slug

Comment: If you visit your site via http://site-testing.com your route links will point to http://site-testing.com, if you visit via https://site-testing.info links will point to https://site-testing.info.